# Pancreas Chitin

Tags: anatomy, biochemistry, armors, bio-mechanics, insectoid

Okay so I am making these arthropod looking humanoid mammalian species, so think of a human with armadillo armor and jointed sloth arms. And I have heard that the pancreas produces Chitin so my question is what would it take for the pancreas to produce enough chitin to make chest, back, and loin armor, mandibles on the chin, along with chitin spikes on the back of the arms and legs and on the the fingers and toes (like a sloth) and for the skin to handle this new feature?

Comment: I'm not sure that the pancreas produces chitin--though the effects of the enzymes produced by the pancreas on chitin (which, btw, is a carbohydrate) have been recorded. In addition keep in mind that the pancreas has much more important functions--digestive ones and regulatory ones. It would probably take a long time. What do you mean by "what would it take?" Not sure here. Please clarify and link to whatever article. This might get a lot of VTC's.

Comment: Whose pancreas produces chitin? In some tetrapods, the pancreas produces [*chitinase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitinase), an [enzyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme) which *breaks down* the chitin in the cell walls or exoscheletons of their prey. In general, mammals don't make chitin; instead of chitin, mammals make and use [keratin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratin), an unrelated substance with certain similar properties and functions. Keratin and chitin have about the same [toughness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toughness), so choosing one or another is a wash.

Comment: Why do you need chitin?   An armadillo's shell is a combination of bone and tough tissue coating.    It is covered in tiny scales made of keratin.  Simply modifying its appearance to be more arthropod-looking would seem to be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: the pancreas can't do it, no matter how much chitin it produces.

Chitin is laid down in place, not circulated.

Pancreatic chitin would not do the job because (best case) it would protect the pancreas, which is tiny and already buried deeply within the abdomen behind layers of intestine, from attacks that would be somewhat inconvenient (say the spear glances off the pancreas and penetrates the aorta and/or several sections of intestine) whether or not the pancreas itself was actually hit.